# How can I create a custom sticky header with auto sliding in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, header, native, sticky

I'm trying to build Sticky Header with resistent sliding.
I mean it should run as the usual sticky header but with auto down/up sliding:
when you pull down a bit (20 pixels) it's sliding down automatically and fully opening itself
and when you pull up a bit from the opened state it's sliding up automatically as well.
Also it has to get moved back if an user stops pulling down|up if this moving is less 20 pixels at top and max_height-20px at bottom.

My code looks like these:

```
useEffect(() => {
    scrollY.addListener((val) => {
        if (val.value < 250) {
            Animated.timing(scrollY, {
                toValue: 0,
                duration: 10 * 0.8,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                easing: Easing.linear,
            }).start(() => {console.log("Animation DONE")})
        }
    })

    return () => {
        scrollY.removeAllListeners();
    };
}, []);  

<Animated.ScrollView
    onScroll={          
        Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }], { useNativeDriver: false },)
    }     
>{props.children}</Animated.ScrollView>
```

But that is not working out. Please help me how can I make this behaviour.